# Four fragments in one activity in Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on an Android application in Xamarin.

1. I want to integrate four fragment in one activity.
2. I want the list in all the fragments
3. On click of a button the fragments gets change.

Or should I use frame layout so that i'll change the UI everytime button get clicked?

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DemoSwipeAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


public DemoSwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return DemoFragment.newInstance();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}


@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return 1f;
}

}
```

Use FargmentPageAdapter.... and set it to viewpage in your Activtiy

Comment: can you please share some example in xamarin?